# Magento2: How to avoid fake registration?

Tags: magento2, customer-registration, spam

How to avoid fake registration?

I have added google ReCaptcha. But getting the same issue.

[image]

Please help me

Comment: Add OTP verification? by mail, if you want to free use. okay.

Comment: I don't think you have properly used Magento 2  Google Captcha.Also, check do you using any other custom form for registration form

Comment: I have not used any custom registration form and google captcha also is working properly. But getting span registration. @AmitBera

Comment: Which google captcha you use? magento default one?

Comment: Yes, Now I am using Magento default one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is some leakage in your Magento instance.

So, you have identified from which URL this fake registration and then apply your fixation.

***let's create plugins on below classes and add the debugger to every plugin and check $_REQUEST value for tracking from URLs this issue happen.***

- `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement`
- `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository`

**Create** `di.xml` at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/` and declare  plugin on this files:

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="StackExchanges_Magento_Plugin_Magento_Customer_Model_AccountManagement" 
                        sortOrder="10" type="{Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="StackExchanges_Magento_Plugin_Magento_Customer_Model_ResourceModel_CustomerRepository"
                        sortOrder="10" type="{Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin Class:**

*First plugin class*

`app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/Plugin/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository.php`

**Code**

```php
<?php


namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel;

/**
 * Class CustomerRepository
 *
 */
class CustomerRepository
{

    private $logger;
    public function __construct(
       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function beforeSave(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository $subject,
        $customer,
        $passwordHash = null
    ) {
        $this->logger->log(100,print_r($_REQUEST,true));
        return [$customer, $passwordHash];
    }
}
```

*Second plugin class*

**Path:** `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/Plugin/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement.phpp`

**Code**

```php
<?php


namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Magento\Customer\Model;

/**
 * Class AccountManagement
 *
 * @package StackExchanges\Magento\Plugin\Magento\Customer\Model
 */
class AccountManagement
{
    private $logger;
    public function __construct(
       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function beforeCreateAccount(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement $subject,
        $redirectUrl = '',
        $password = null,
        $customer
    ) {
        $this->logger->log(100,print_r($_REQUEST,true));
        return [$redirectUrl, $password, $customer];
    }
}
```

**See at every plugin I have added logger** `$this->logger->log(100,print_r($_REQUEST,true))` to t**rack check what is  post when trying to create customer or save customer.**

and the logs will print on `var/log/debug.log` files.

From these log files, you can find from which URLs(like `customer/account/create`)  the data is posting and the customer is creating and you can analyze the data.

If you **will find that url from where the wrong customer register, then you reverify why google captcha is not working** or if not working you can **fix that also**. Implement the fixation accordingly.

### Apply some solution to stop the fake user to register

Suppose, if the email like `mail.ru`, you want to stop register, then add below code before `$this->logger->log(100,print_r($_REQUEST,true));` at this two plugin.

```php
        if (strpos($email, 'mail.ru') !== false) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException(__('Invalid Customer register.'));
        }
```

***Example***

```php
<?php


namespace StackExchanges\Magento\Plugin\Magento\Customer\Model;

/**
 * Class AccountManagement
 *
 * @package StackExchanges\Magento\Plugin\Magento\Customer\Model
 */
class AccountManagement
{
    private $logger;
    public function __construct(
       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function beforeCreateAccount(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement $subject,
        $redirectUrl = '',
        $password = null,
        $customer
    ) {

        $email = $customer->getEmail();
        // match and throw error for stop registraion
        if (strpos($email, 'mail.ru') !== false) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException(__('Invalid Customer register.'));
        }
        $this->logger->log(100,print_r($_REQUEST,true));
        return [$redirectUrl, $password, $customer];
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check and update you soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Custom Captcha (with some complex algorithm)** is best option for you as you don't want to integrate OTP functionality in registration page.

There is also one option if you know the email domains which are registered as a fake customer as per your screenshot is **mail.ru**, for this you need to add some custom code in your customer create controller class, for reference please check below sample code :

```
if($postrequest['email']) {
    $rejectList =  array('mailinator','mail.ru','yopmail'); //you can mention as many email domains as per your need
    $str = explode('@',$postrequest['email'],2);
    $domain = explode('.',$str[1],2);
    if(in_array($domain[0],$rejectList)) {
        $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Enter valid domain name in Email.'));
        return $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($defaultUrl));
    }
}
```

Please let me know this solution is working for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid fake registration.

1. Put OTP verification by mobile or email.

That is the best way, because who is genuine that user only verifies their number.

Comment: I like your thoughts but I want to avoid fake registration without OTP.

Comment: Okay, make one input box with randoms generated captcha. like 1234 and input box. may be  less fake registration

Comment: please follow this https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/prevent-spam-account-registration-in-magento2-670 and  3rd point.

Comment: I will try and update you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We're using MSP ReCaptcha which allows you to use Google ReCaptcha v3 API and invisble Captcha. It is much more effective against bots. For us this has made a huge difference in the amount of Russian spam account.

https://github.com/magento/magespecialist_ReCaptcha/

Answer (score 0):

there is a paid and unpaid solution if you want to go with paid use SMS Authentication for new sign-up if you want to go with free option use Google Recaptcha & email verification required for new signup!